# Add map overlay from drawable that spans entire map

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-mapview

I have an Android mapview (using Xamarin) that contains two collections of markers, one for property markers and the other for traffic count markers. I need to add a translucent overlay to the map in between the two collections of markers, so that the traffic count markers are above it and are alpha = 1, and the property markers and map tiles are below it and are alpha = .5.

[image]

This doesn't seem like it should be too tricky, but I haven't found any examples online of how to create an overlay of a drawable (a translucent 1x1 pixel png image) and stretch it across the map.

My best guess is that I need to use a tile overlay... I saw that there is a UrlTileProvider but that's for loading a url, not a drawable. Also there is the option of implementing ITileProvider directly, however I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: An image or two might be helpful to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Added!